# Can I determine interface requirements/dependencies/inheritance programatically?

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0

Is there a way (reflection or otherwise) to programatically determine that the IList interface requires ICollection, which in turn requires IEnumerable?

I'm working on a [reflection library](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) and came across a scenario where I could use this information, but found no way to obtain it. Both the compiler and the IDE (obviously) know the relation, so it must be available somehow.

I'm hoping for suggestions that don't involve IL or source parsing, neither of which really is an option for my use case.

Comment: COM objects can do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx) to discover this information.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, just shows how fast you can go about forgetting something if you don't work with it for a while :)

Comment: Actually, it seems like recursion isn't even needed (I get an array with all the required interfaces).

Comment: @MortenMertner: ...which validates your first comment once more :-)

Answer (score 1):

Examples below in powershell:

```
PS C:\> [collections.ilist].getinterfaces()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ICollection
True     False    IEnumerable
```

The equivalent in c# would be: `typeof(IList).GetInterfaces()`.